# embeded .SWF file goes crazy in IE but not in other browsers

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, internet-explorer, sharepoint

I'm building a SharePoint page with an embedded .swf file that is capable of detecting the current URL to activate and show content. Everything goes smoothly in all the browsers I've tested it except IE. When I open the SharePoint page in IE the .swf just reproduces the frames non stop. It completely ignores my scripts, and I cant find anything that could be responsible of this. The URL detection script is the next one:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;

if (ExternalInterface.available)
{
    var url:String = ExternalInterface.call("window.location.href.toString");
    if (url == "https://example1.aspx"){
        gotoAndStop(1)
    }
    else if (url == "https://example2.aspx"){
        gotoAndStop(2)
    }
    else if (url == "https://example3.aspx"){
        gotoAndStop(3)
    }
    else if (url == "https://example4.aspx"){
        gotoAndStop(4)
    }
}
```

Every other scripts are just buttons configuration inside the time line and stops. so I'm pretty sure that the problem is not there.

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: Show us the code for gotoAndStop.  What you've shown so far can't be used to diagnose the problem.

Comment: could be a Flash Player version problem, the swf targets one version that is not available.

Comment: Robbert, the codes of my buttons are simple event listeners of gotoAndStop(#), and some navigateToURL. the stops are just "stop();" everything is really simple, that why im so confused about this situation. (DX)